# Gmaps4Rails - How to use addMarkers() function with animation?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have an ajax function responsible for retrieving and adding new markers according to user's dragging and dropping on map. When adding, I'd like to use bounce animation, like this one:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations?hl=pt-br

How can I do it on addMarkers function?

`Gmaps.map.addMarkers(response);`

Thanks!

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: customizing gmaps4rails in v1 was really hard, unless you edit the js. (here for your purpose: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/1.x/app/assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee#L268) I really recommend you migrate to v2